# Set variables in xml just like manifest placeholders in android for adMob

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, admob, build.gradle

Manifest placeholders in the `build.gradle` file allows you to specify constants that can then be used in the `manifest` file like so.

```
  manifestPlaceholders = [admob_app_id: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713", banner_id: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"]
```

and then in the manifest file

```xml
 <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="${admob_app_id}" />
```

This does not seem to work in case of layout xml files

```xml
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/publisherAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="${banner_id}" />
```

Is there a way I can dynamically change the `banner id` based on the build config. I have tried doing it programmatically but admob throws keeps complaining unless both `adSize` and `adUnitId` are declared in xml.

Comment: You can have different versions of the layout resource in source sets based on the build variant. Or, if the library supports it, use a string resource that you set in Gradle via `resValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `resValue()` method](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips) to create a string resource with your banner id, and then reference that in your layouts:

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      resValue("string", "banner_id", "foo")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      resValue("string", "banner_id", "bar")
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"
```